# Unable to display emoji expressions after the rotation of the canvas in the Safari and Chrome browsers on the Mac platform

Tags: javascript, html, macos, google-chrome, safari

> MacOS:10.13.2
>
> Chrome:67.0.3396.99
>
> Safari:11.0.2 (13604.4.7.1.3)

I rotate the canvas to display the text, the normal text is displayed normally, but the text content cannot be displayed when it is an emoji expression.

```
var mCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(mCanvas);
mCanvas.width = 600;
mCanvas.height = 600;
var mctx = mCanvas.getContext('2d');
mctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
mctx.rotate(5);
mctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
mctx.fillText('', 100, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emoji content works fine with canvas. Seems like the text position after rotate is not where you expect it to see. Please check this example https://jsfiddle.net/jzysyfrr/57/

Lines:

```
context.rotate(5);
context.fillText( '', index * 140 -20, 90 );
```